# Не работает char.ToLower и char.ToUpper

Tags: c#

Символ под чётным индексом должен становится в верхнем регистре, нечётный в нижнем. Написанный код не работает. Пробовал создавать отдельную переменную для array[j] и её уже преобразовывать и после заменять на неё, но также не выходит.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ToWeirdCase("This is a test");
    }

    public static string ToWeirdCase(string s)
    {
        string[] words = s.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            char[] array = words[i].ToCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0)
                    char.ToUpper(array[j]);
                else
                    char.ToLower(array[j]);
            }
            words[i] = new string(array);
        }

        return string.Join(" ", words);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри что возвращает вызов `char.ToUpper(array[j])` - он возвращает тебе преобразованный символ, ты его должен перезаписать по нужному индексу и все будет ок

```
  for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
  {
    if (j % 2 == 0)
      array[j] = char.ToUpper(array[j]);
    else
      array[j] = char.ToLower(array[j]);
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, невнимателен был

Comment: можешь пометить ответ как правильный галочкой слева от ответа